# Std::wstring behavior in C++: debug executable using release library

Tags: c++, stl, wstring

Suppose that executable uses dynamic library exposing the following dummy f-n and class, which uses `std::wstring`:

Header:

```
size_t LIBDLL_API strF( std::wstring const& str );

class LIBDLL_API StringClass
{
public:
    StringClass();
    StringClass( std::wstring const& str );
    ~StringClass();

    int length() const;
    std::wstring const& str();

private:
    std::wstring _str;
};
```

CPP:

```
#include "library.h"

StringClass::~StringClass()
{}

StringClass::StringClass()
{}

StringClass::StringClass( std::wstring const& str ) :
_str( str )
{}

int StringClass::length() const
{
    return _str.size();
}

std::wstring const& StringClass::str()
{
    return _str;
}

size_t strF( std::wstring const& str )
{
    return str.size();
}
```

The above library is built in release mode. If the executable project is run in Release mode, all is fine; however, when *Debug* executable calls into release library, the following:

```
StringClass cl( L"Hello" );
std::wcout << cl.str() << "\t" << cl.length() << std::endl;
```

throws with `std::length_error`:

```
_CRTIMP2_PURE _NO_RETURN(__CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Xlength_error(_In_z_ const char *_Message))
    {   // report a length_error
    _THROW_NCEE(length_error, _Message);
    }
```

and `strF( L"Hello" )` returns 14757395255531667567.

What's the problem here and how debug/release can even affect anything in this example? If someone has 3rd-party library which was built in release mode (headers, lib, dll) - does it mean that he can't debug his own program, which just uses the library?

Comment: You have to obey the One Definition Rule.  You can disable optimizations and enable debug information while still using the release library, but you'll have to set macros such as `_DEBUG` and `NDEBUG` to match the library.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Thanks for advice! I just tried to set NDEBUG in the executable project, but got exactly same exception thrown. Please also see the edit about 3rd libraries

Comment: Make a new configuration, copying from "Release", and just reduce optimization level and turn on debug info.  But leave all the macros identical to "Release" configuration.  Does anything change?

Comment: @BenVoigt - thanks again. I followed your advice, and I think I found one single compiler option that changes the behavior. So the crash in executable run occurs when CRT is set to `/MDd`.. if I change it to `/MD` or even to `/MTd` then it works with Debug EXE -> Release DLL... The library project links CRT/MFC statically... What's going on, can you explain? Also, with third party libraries, everyone must go through this? Thanks

Comment: When you use `/MDd` you promise to use the debug DLL later.

Comment: To help in finding common errors, many of the classes in the Microsoft headers have different sizes when built in debug (controlled by `_DEBUG` and `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` macros) than they do in release so you can't mix the two.  There's a base class to `wstring` that is different sizes between debug and release.  To debug in release just include the debug symbols in your build (and probably dial the optimization level way down).